# 'webrtc_android' makes error messages on build

Tags: javascript, java, android, webrtc

I get a problem when webrtc_android is build.

```
vagrant@precise64:~/webrtc_checkout/src$ tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py
```

And I get an error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/tools/lint/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I don't know why I get those messages.

How can I fix it? Help me please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem myself.

When you get the error, try followings..

1. install openjdk-8-jdk

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Change your openjdk version

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ...
   2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
   ```
3. Try again

   `tools_webrtc/android/build_aar.py`

Comment: Got here by googling the error message. I also had to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable for it to work e.g.:

     JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Comment: This also solves an issue when attempting to compile Chromium using an EC2 instance running a stock Amazon Linux AMI.  It defaults to Java 1.7, and the Chromium build tools pick that up even though it requires Java 1.8.